# LongListSelector with cells of varying heights?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I'm looking to use the `LongListSelector` to display two columns of images, the catch is that the images are of various heights and a static known width.

An example of the layout would be:

```
+--------+ +--------+
|  img1  | |  img2  |
|        | |        |
+--------+ |        |
+--------+ |        |
|  img3  | +--------+
|        | +--------+
|        | |  img4  |
|        | |        |
+--------+ |        |
           +--------+
```

I found a project that shows a grid of images, called PhotoHubSample (from http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/PhotoHub-Windows-Phone-8-fd7a1093), however this uses a consistent width and height - leading me to believe it's not possible to do what I want.

I can't see any other Windows Phone 8 examples, however if you want to see a real world example - the Pinterest app on the iPhone renders this kind of list... is there a way to do it in XAML? I'm not 100% set on using `LongListSelector` if there is an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the `VariableSizedWrapGrid` and `WrapPanel` but both required known heights and widths (or proportions thereof). Since I knew my image width (half the screen width on the phone) I would be sizing the height of the image to ensure correct scaling. This meant the height was variable.

To achieve this, I created a ViewModel that had two image sources a 'LeftImage' and a 'RightImage' as well as a computed 'YOffset'. Now each Item in my `LongListSelector` would have the following XAML;

```
    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="0,0,0,17">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="14" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Source="{Binding LeftImageUri}" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Stretch="None"/>
                <Canvas Grid.Column="2">
                    <Image Source="{Binding RightImageUri}" Stretch="None" Margin="{Binding YOffset, Converter={StaticResource ThicknessTopConverter}}"/>
                </Canvas>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
```

I used an `IValueConverter` to create the `Thickness` object required for the vertical offset of the second image and wrapped this in a `Canvas` so that it could spill over the boundaries of the `Grid`.

To generate my ViewModel items I take the list of images and do a simple bin sorting algorithm between the Left and Right sides, making sure I always have an image in the left to match. I keep a running count of the offset and set appropriately on each item in the ViewModel collection.

It's a bit hacky as it's not pure XAML, and I'm sure I could turn it into a proper control, but this works fine for the one scrolling list I need. I also get all the benefits of the `LongListSelector`, I'll be implementing infinite scrolling eventually so all I need to keep track of in the ViewModel is the ongoing offset.

A view of what it looks like with 400px and 600px images is below (actual screenshot);

[image: WP8 with Two Column Layout]

Comment: Your solution looks great! A user control or test example proj on GitHub would be awesome...

Comment: Thanks! Good idea - I'm sure the (somewhat messy) code will improve as I iron out some bugs in the next few weeks. Looks like I need the list in two places now so maybe a `UserControl` will come about... thanks for all your suggestions and I'll update this answer when I get around to uploading a sample.

Answer (score 0):

There is a variable sized wrap grid control available in the Kinnara wp toolkit... maybe it can help? You can get it [at github here...](https://github.com/Kinnara/WPToolkit)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I'll have a look in the next few days if this can handle my needs. Hopefully it will still behave with long lists. If it ends up being not particularly responsive I'll have to fall back to a simple one column list.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for what I need... the 'ItemHeight' and 'ItemWidth' need to be set on the `VariableSizedWrapGrid` so this is a great control for known proportions (such as the Start screen in Windows 8) but I don't know the height of my images until runtime, and they vary which breaks the layout calculation in this control. Thanks for the suggestion though. Any other ideas?

Comment: Damn, would have been great if it worked for your scenario! You 'could' raise your problem on the github? Maybe they can take a look at another solution?

Comment: On the other hand there is also a WrapPanel in the phone toolkit, would that help? http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/wp7-wrappanel-in-depth

Comment: I tried this as well, suffers from the same requirement for real estate. Since my images are of different heights they can overlap vertically with each row. I'll add an answer here shortly on how I've achieved the desired result - unfortunately I had to change my ViewModel to accommodate.